# Anyway to determine line count for a itextsharp pdfField when filling the form?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to fill out a form that consists of a description, quantity, rate and total for a particular work item to be performed by a technician.

the description can span multiple lines, while the other info is just one line. The form can have multiple work items, so my question is, how can I line up the quantity, rate and total so it lines up against the top line of each description.

Sample:

```
DESCRIPTION                       QUANTITY         RATE         TOTAL
ajsdfasdfsafasfadfasdfsadfasfaf       1            99.99       99.99
odaasdfalkfjlaksjfdalsfjaslfj
sadflaksdfjasfdlakjdfasdlfkjas

Second item....adsadadasdasda         1            99.99       99.99
.
.
.
```

There is other information in the top half of the form that gets filled in, so I can't really use a table. I basically feed my data in a string builder and then send it to the field, but the pdfstamper takes care of word wrapping but never returns a line count and Times New Roman is inconsistent, so I can really take my own line count based on character width.

Idea's?

Comment: You say "form", this is a logical form and not an `AcroForm`, right?

Comment: Also, you say there's more information at the top but I don't understand why you can't just put that information out and then throw a table underneath it. Can you explain that some more?

Comment: My application is taking data from Quickbooks and printing an estimate. This estimate is a standard template in Quickbooks. I scanned a blank estimate into a PDF and using pdfFill, I created some fields which are accessible through iTextSharp AcroFields. The top of half of the page contains a information related to estimate number, date, address of customer, etc. And then the bottom section gets filled with the above information. The template is already pre-formatted with a border, etc. Not sure how printing a table would help.

Answer (score 0):

well, turns out that I implemented my solution in a different manner. I ended up generating a table, and then calling WriteSelectedRows to pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1).

I had to play with the table column dimensions to get the exact format I needed and as I am adding content, check the totalHeight to determine when to break to a new page.

It took some math guess work to determine the exact dimensions, but overall, using the PdfPTable was the right solution.